Why use scale() on canvas?
I was using canvas when I saw an image painted on canvas showing blur. I found the cause and solution to this. However, there is something I don't understand. It's context.scale().
I don't know in detail what function scale(dpr, dpr) is, but I think maybe this will adjust css pixel to physical pixel to fit dpr value. If my guess is correct, I have a question.
I'm using an environment(display) with a dpr value of 2.
I'm using an environment(display) where the dpr value is 2. I think that even without the context.scale(), the CSS pixels of the canvas will be automatically adjusted to physical pixels.
Because my display has a dpr value of 2..
So, why do I use the context.scale(dpr, dpr)?
Isn't it unnecessary?
Most of the codes I looked for for blur troubleshooting were using the scale().


const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio

canvas.style.width = "300px";
canvas.style.height = "400px";


canvas.width = dpr * 300;
canvas.height = dpr * 400;

// ctx.scale(dpr, dpr); // Isn't it unnecessary?
ctx.strokeRect(100, 100, 150, 150);
<canvas id="screen"></canvas>




Have you looked at this documentation?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale

In this case scale is being used to alter the dimensions of the rectangular box as per the "devicePixelRatio". So when devicePixelRatio = 1.1 and if you don't use the scale then the dimensions of rectangle drawn will be 150 * 150 but if you use scale then dimensions of rectangle drawn will be 166 * 166.
I hope this makes sense.
